# handling multiple fragments values

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have to create an application which handle three fragments with in same activity. when I click button in left side the corresponding fragments are shown in right side layouts, and when the fragments are changed I need to keep the values selected in the fragment when the fragment is again replaced. I want to show the selected values also.
please help me to do this here is the example:

[this is the design i make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oWFb.png)

Comment: You need to improve the format of the question. and you should include more detail information about problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a method as a listener for button in the left panel which "installs" the fragment on the right panel.

Comment: i have the listner but when new fragment is attached in button click and old fragments values get disappeared please give me a solution

Comment: When you attach new fragment you won't have access to the values from the other fragments because they aren't there in that moment. If you need  data from the old fragments you should save this data.

Comment: how can i save that data please give me an example

Comment: If you don't put your code I can't figure out why you want access to data from another inactive fragments and I don't know how I can help you.